# Obtener horas laboradas semanalmente tipo project manager en .net (c# or vb.net)

Tags: c#, vb.net

El problema es el siguiente:
Se debe calcular el tiempo total de una tarea; dada un día con hora (para el comienzo) y un tiempo asignado para la tarea.
 Ej. se comienza el 15 oct de 2018 a las 2:00pm, una tarea que durara 33.5hrs laborables. Se debe calcular cuando terminaria asumiendo que los almuerzos, comidas y descansos no cuentan como parte del horario laborable y cada día tiene distintos intervalos no laborables

El mejor ejemplo son las tareas asignables en project manager donde ajustan cada dia con los intervalos no laborables y se pone la fecha de comienzo y el tiempo asignado y da la fecha de terminacion automatica

Comment: y cual es tu duda respecto a esa consigna?

Comment: Hola @Edgar Lopez, para poder ayudarte seria bueno que pusieras lo que has intentando, ya que la comunidad lo que trata es de ayudarte en tus dudas de algo que has intentado y no has podido lograrlo. Podrias

Comment: Ocupo un ejemplo de como hacerlo, la verdad me he dado por vencido, intente sumarle a la fecha inicial los descansos que se atarviesen pero me sigue sin calcular bien la fecha final, ya que en ocasiones me da que termina en domingo (no laborable) o en un almuerzo